# Cargo install not working with certificate error

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

This is working fine in old projects strangely but if i do cargo new project_name
and add any dependency or try to install a dependency via cargo install, i get:

for example:

```
cargo install reqwest

    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to download from `https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/reqwest/0.11.14/download`

Caused by:
  [60] SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired)
```

Comment: It says "certificate has expired". Some times that is the case because your system clock isn't set correctly. Maybe try re-syncing it

Comment: Is your versions of cargo up to date?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can skip the ssl check as below.

First, create a config file as below. Replace with your proxy.

```
[http]
  sslVerify = false
  proxy = http://proxy:port
```

Then, specify the config and run:

```
GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=config GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true cargo update --verbose
```